# Password issue on iPhone 6s saying password is too short

Tags: iphone, ios, password

When I try and change my iPhone 6s password I click "custom numeric password" and I type in a 3 digit code and it says "make password longer". Then it would be a 4 digit code and that's not what I want.

[image]

Comment: Try clicking "passcode options" I'm pretty sure there should be a custom option.

Comment: You can try what @Joonas said...but I would say 4 digits is a tad more secure ;)

Comment: My guess is that "custom" was never meant to mean "shorter". As the default is now 6 digits, presumably the old minimum of 4 still stands.

Comment: Just to clarify, prior to getting the screen above do you first see the _This passcode can be easily guessed_ message with the 'Use Anyway' option?

Comment: The 'Use Anyway' option _looks_ like it would let you use a 1-3 character password but iOS still requires the passcode to be at least four characters/numbers long. @Monomeeth

Answer (score 1):

The **minimum passcode length** for custom numeric passcodes is **four characters**. The same applies for custom alphanumeric passcodes.

I've also tried this on an iPhone 6s running iOS 10.3.2.

If you want a passcode that's easier to type (which I don't recommend) you may want to use repeating numbers (e.g. 1122 or 2255).